# Java: Return an int out of a var, containing letters and figures

Tags: java, integer

i hope someone can help me, i have the following problem.
I have a variable that looks like this:

```
var a = "01VENT000KRV010WFEVVV055";
```

I would like to either:

- have the last 3 figures of the variable (e.g. 055) as an int
- or remove ALL non-figures out of the variable (e.g. 01000010055) as an int

My idea was that:

```
int sub = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(a.length-3));
```

or:

```
int sub = Integer.parseInt(a.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

That didnt work, so i would really appreciate if someone could help me here
Thanks

Comment: you should handle the leading zero `0`,

Comment: @Kent Integer.parseInt will take care of leading zeros.

Comment: hmmm and how? any help?

Comment: I tried both ur solution and both work :D.

Comment: What does "Didn't work" mean. Because `a.length` should be `a.length()`. That works perfectly fine

Comment: perhaps the compilation error `var a = ...`  and `a.length` ? it is javascript syntax, isn't it?

Comment: Well i exactly use that lines in a import script:
`var variantPriority = node.queryString("GROUP_NAME");`
`int variantPrio = Integer.parseInt(variantPriority.substring(variantPriority.length-3, variantPriority.length));`
  
`importer.set("priority", variantPrio);`

As error i get:
missing ; before statement

Comment: Are you trying to extract the numbers from the string or extract the letters from the string?

Comment: the numbers from a string

Comment: Seems to have sth to do with the identier "int"...

Answer (score 0):

> Note all methods can potentially return an empty string.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String a = "01VENT000KRV010WFEVVV055";
        System.out.println(removeChars(a));
        System.out.println(removeDigits(a));
        System.out.println(getLastThreeChars(a));
    }


    //This method removes Characters from a string and returns a String of numbers
    static String removeChars(String t)
    {
        String tempString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++)
        {            
            if(Character.isDigit(t.charAt(i)))
            {
                tempString += t.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        return tempString;
    }

    //This method removes Digits from a string and returns only characters
    static String removeDigits(String t)
    {
        String tempString = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++)
        {            
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(t.charAt(i)))
            {
                tempString += t.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        return tempString;
    }

    //This methods prints the last 3 char of a string
    static String getLastThreeChars(String t)
    {
        StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = t.length() - 1; i > t.length() - 1 - 3; i--)
        {
            tempString.append(t.charAt(i));
        }

        return tempString.reverse().toString();
    }
```

[image]